# How can I store Unchecked box data in database in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox, unchecked

In PHP I used Multi check box in foreach loop, When I Unchecked then I want to count and store that data in Database and also for Checked data, so How can I do that?
And I've a condition for that it is...

```
If(checked)
{
 Insert Present
}
Elseif(Unchecked)
{
 Insert Absent
}
```

Check box is in foreach loop, so there is multiple checkbox with different names.

Here presently I store data for Checked, but I can't store data for Unchecked, so please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go for pseudo logic for this.

Store a hidden variable with all the checkbox values.

e.g.

`<input type="hidden" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" name="allCheckboxes"/>`

In the form submit, you are already getting the checked values.

Say, you get `5,7,9` as checked. `-> Present`

You need then `1,2,3,4,6,8` as unchecked. `-> Absent`

This can be achieved through array and string operations between `allCheckboxes` and checked checkboxes.

Comment: Here is my code:   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  <input type="checkbox" name="att[]" value="<?php echo $row["enrollno"]; ?>" checked>
}